# Is there a Javascript function to invert all the colors (negative effect) of the camera?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

So, I am using Appcelerator Titanium (NOT ALLOY) to build an App (for Android mostly) that opens the camera and reads a QR Code. So far, so good, it does what it should be. But, there is some versions of QRCode that have inverted colors, and my App isn't able to read them. So, I am trying to find a way to invert the view of the camera as well, so the QRCode can be read as a normal QRCode.

I have tried some functions to turn the colors hex code into RGB. Bellow I will post some parts of the code for example.

Please, if anyone has a solution, help me! =)

I have tried to use CSS to add filters, but it is only possible in Alloy, not common Ti.UI projects, which is my case.

```
    var overlay = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    id: 'overlay',
});
//the overlay is called when the camera opens, it is the main view in which I have to invert the colors....

function rgbaToHex(r, g, b, a) {
    var toHex = function(n) {
        return ('00' + (n | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    };
    return '#' + toHex(((a * 100) / 100) * 255) + toHex(r) + toHex(g) + toHex (b);
};
//this is a rgba to hex function I found on the web, and it works, just not as I need it....
```

Comment: you can't use CSS filters, even with Alloy. CSS has nothing todo with Titanium. There is TSS. And it wouldn't help to create some kind of overlay that will turn the colors since the barcode reader (I guess ti.barcode?) is a native module that reads out the camera stream. Or you have to take a picture, invert that and use the static (from file) QR reader. But then I would use a module or hyperloop to invert the colors which would be way faster (have a look at https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples there is a filter example).Or extend ti.barcode to use KEY_INVERT_SCAN (search source)

Comment: Thanks for the tip man. I will check out your recommendations. While I check it, is there a module that can do this already? Because, I have checked for several QR Code readers on AppStore, some of them read the inverted QRCode, some doesn't. Maybe what I need is just a module that can do this.

Comment: you mean other apps? Yes, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android has an inverted scan option. Ti.barcode has the option but it is not exposed. You have to add it there to use it or try to set it via XML (not done this before)

Comment: Hey, how are you?
So, I've been on this for a few days now. You mentioned to use the final string KEY_INVERT_SCAN, where exactly should I turn it on/true ? On the capture() method? It calls for the InvertedLuminanceSource automatically? Thanks for the help....

Comment: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/aa7ffe059df720d2d079d0e5494b365b7af7441c/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java#L156 and try it with https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/4199e41fb8bb7fa39d3827f7c892f3611d2fb654/android/res/xml/preferences.xml this xml. If that doesn't work you have to extend the module to make it a parameter you can set in the capture method.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for all the help.
It didn't work only with setting the prefs to true, so I will have to mess with the capture() instead. It is this guy, right?
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/aa7ffe059df720d2d079d0e5494b365b7af7441c/android/src/ti/barcode/BarcodeModule.java#L263

Comment: Can't get it to work at all..... if I add invert() to parse method on BarcodeModule https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/aa7ffe059df720d2d079d0e5494b365b7af7441c/android/src/ti/barcode/BarcodeModule.java#L227 , would it do the job?

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is not the place to do this discussion :-) You could use a parameter like this https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/aa7ffe059df720d2d079d0e5494b365b7af7441c/android/src/ti/barcode/BarcodeModule.java#L298 but I don't know where to use it at the end since it would take to much time to do the whole job. Try to ask at https://tislack.org// in the modules or job section, perhaps someone can extend it for you.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for all your help. When I finally get over this thing, I will let you know what I did to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ZXing, which I assume you are, and if you just want to read the inverted code colours, try adding this on `decode()` at the DecodeHandler class:

```
if (rawResult == null) {
    LuminanceSource invertedSource = source.invert();
    bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(invertedSource));
    try {
      rawResult = multiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
      // continue
    } finally {
      multiFormatReader.reset();
    }
  }
```

It won't invert the camera to negative, but it will work just as it was a regular barcode/QRCode.